# WPF LiveChart: How to Change Color of Gridlines of CartesianChart

Tags: wpf, livecharts

I'm new to WPF [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net) library. Just wanted to know how can I change the color and style of Gridlines of a chart object. The default is set to Gray  I believe. Please see attached.

[image]

Here is the code snippet for chart object:

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart   Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Name="chartObj"  >

            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis MinValue="0"  MaxValue="{Binding MaxXAxisValue}" ></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>

            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY >
            <lvc:Axis MinValue="0"   MaxValue="10" ></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Any idea or solution will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The demo you are running, has a theme:

https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Themes

Documentation is being updated based on the most frequent question in this first year and a half, hopefully this will be more clear.

The theme sets the default separator style:

```
<Style TargetType="lvc:Separator">
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#1A303030"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="AxisOrientation" Value="X">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

You can customize this theme, or override it for your chart:

```
 <lvc:CartesianChart   Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" Name="chartObj"  >

        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis MinValue="0"  MaxValue="{Binding MaxXAxisValue}" >
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                   <lvc:Separator Stroke="Red"/>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
```